# In C#, How to convert a hexdecimal string to int?

Tags: c#

How do I convert the following string:

```
6F
```

for example, to a normal int? It's hexdecimal value.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214980/convert-a-single-hex-character-to-its-byte-value-in-c/1215076#1215076

Answer (score 11):

```
string s = "6F";
int i = Int32.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
Console.WriteLine(i); // prints "111" to the console
```

For details on `NumberStyles`, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx).

Comment: It would actually be better to use int.Parse, rather than int32.

Comment: Just a style recommendation.  If you're declaring your variable as "int", then you should use "int.Parse()".  If you're using Int32, then use Int32.Parse().  You should really follow a standard usage, whichever one you pick.

Comment: @womp, I actually prefer the style Jason used, for some reason it feels more natural it's like saying declare a primitive int and call the method Parse on Int32 class.

Answer (score 5):

```
 int num = Int32.Parse(strValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert.ToInt32(stringValue,16);

Where last param is base of 16